# Spring Security. Проверка токена на каждый http-запрос

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-security

У меня есть сервис на Spring Boot, который принимает REST-запросы. Необходимо сделать на каждый запрос проверку переданного токена в заголовке. Проверка будет осуществляться через вызов внешнего сервиса.

Возможно такую задачу реализовать на Spring Security?
Если да, то каким образом? Есть у кого нибудь похожие наработки?

Comment: За валидацию токена отвечает `org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.authentication.OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter`.  По идее вы его можете унаследовать, вписать свою логику в метод `doFilter` и использовать его вместо стандартной реализации.

Comment: Либо перед этим фильтром или после него добавить свой фильтр, который будет делать то, что вам нужно. Пожалуй так даже правильнее будет.